# CSS donut chart with borders only adds border to top

Tags: css, css-shapes

I have this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kywetbeL/19/ and in only CSS and HTML. I wanted to make a donut chart that had 5 chunks and a border and a small gap between each part.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.donut-chart {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 2rem;
  border-radius: 100%
}

p.center {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 15% 0 0;
}

.portion-block {
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 200px, 200px, 100px);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  clip: rect(0px, 100px, 200px, 0px);
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#part1 {
  transform: rotate(326deg);
}

#part1 .circle {
  background-color: #E64C65;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  animation: first 1s 1 forwards;
}

#part2 {
  transform: rotate(38deg);
}

#part2 .circle {
  background-color: #11A8AB;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  animation: second 1s 1 forwards 1s;
}

#part3 {
  transform: rotate(110deg);
}

#part3 .circle {
  background-color: #4FC4F6;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  animation: third 0.5s 1 forwards 2s;
}

#part4 {
  transform: rotate(182deg);
}

#part4 .circle {
  background-color: #4FC433;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  animation: fourth 0.5s 1 forwards 3s;
}

#part5 {
  transform: rotate(254deg);
}

#part5 .circle {
  background-color: #4FC888;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  animation: fifth 0.5s 1 forwards 4s;
}


/* Animation */

@keyframes first {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(68deg);
  }
}

@keyframes second {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(68deg);
  }
}

@keyframes third {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(68deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fourth {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(68deg);
  }
}

@keyframes fifth {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(68deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="donut-chart-block block">
    <div class="donut-chart">
      <div id="part1" class="portion-block">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="part2" class="portion-block">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="part3" class="portion-block">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="part4" class="portion-block">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="part5" class="portion-block">
        <div class="circle"></div>
      </div>
      <p class="center"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't seem to get the border around the entire element, only the top.

Comment: I do see a border around the entire chart - 1px black border, right? Can you provide any additional details on what you're not seeing, or browser version?

Comment: I want each div (each differently colored section) to have its own border not the whole circle.

Comment: The black borders are technically all around the outside of the circle. The clip property is just cutting them off.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. Anyone have any ideas on how to get it to show?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do it with just css. You might have to use svgs to accomplish this.

Comment: It's the .circle elements inside your blocks that have the border, so where is the problem with giving each one a different border-color? https://jsfiddle.net/kywetbeL/27/

Answer (score 1):

I would first update your code using my previous answer and then consider a filter to create a border:

```css
.palette {
  --g: 10px; /* The gap between shapes*/
  --s: 50px; /* the size*/

  width: 250px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: inline-grid;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 1px #000) drop-shadow(0 0 0 #000) drop-shadow(0 0 0 #000) drop-shadow(0 0 0 #000)
}
.palette > * {
  grid-area: 1/1;
  position: relative;
  clip-path:polygon(
    calc(50% + var(--g)/2) 50%, 
    calc(50% + var(--g)/2) 0%, 
    100% 0%,
    100% calc(33.745% - var(--g)/2),
    50% calc(50% - var(--g)/2)); 
}
.palette > *:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: var(--s) solid #0000;
  border-left-color: var(--c);
  animation:m 1s linear both var(--d,0s);
}
@keyframes m {
  from{transform:rotate(45deg)}
  to  {transform:rotate(135deg)}
}

.color1 {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  --c: red;
}
.color2 {
  transform: rotate(72deg);
  --c:blue;
  --d:1s;
}
.color3 {
  transform: rotate(144deg);
  --c:orange;
  --d:2s;
}
.color4 {
  transform: rotate(216deg);
  --c:green;
  --d:3s;
}
.color5 {
  transform: rotate(288deg);
  --c:purple;
  --d:4s;
}
```

```html
<div class="palette">
  <div class="color1"></div>
  <div class="color2"></div>
  <div class="color3"></div>
  <div class="color4"></div>
  <div class="color5"></div>
</div>
```